# Cmake stuck when building

Tags: compiling, cmake

I downloaded the latest cmake(v3.11) source I am trying to build by running `./configure` or `./boostrap` but it gets stuck all the time at

```
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95
```

I even tried with an earlier version but the same issue occurred. The problem is, I have to build a library from source, it is configured to attempt to download and build cmake, and of course, the library building process gets stuck too.

Comment: I'm confused. If you downloaded a *binary* `cmake` package, what are you building? if you are building something else that uses `cmake`, why is `./configure` involved (since that's typically part of the `automake` build system)?

Comment: @s I am building a library, google c++  sdk client  library, at some point it download cmake and attempt to use it to build some of its libraries.

Comment: Maybe if `cmake` was already present on your system (`sudo apt install cmake`) it would not try to download and build it?

Comment: @steeldriver The thing is I have cmake already installed, but the install script for the library was written to download and install it. The way I see it, I should be able to install cmake from binaries. Please, you could have a try and see if you could.

Comment: @T.Obadiah Can you give a link to the library you are trying to build?

Comment: Do you have a FORTRAN compiler installed? ie `which f95` (unlikely) or `which gfortran` (common). Cross-site related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852420/looking-for-a-fortran-compiler-usr-bin-f95-when-install-cmake-3-10-3